# removing whitespace on beginning of json data

Tags: php, arrays, json

how to remove whitespace on beginning of a JSON string.

example:

`{ "name" : " Test Subject" }`

to

`{ "name" : "Test Subject" }`

the space before 'Test' to be removed

Comment: Use [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: A simple 1 liner for all values, `echo json_encode(array_map('trim',json_decode($json, true)));`

Comment: @Xorifelse In fact you dont even need the `array_map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution using `json_decode` and `trim` functions:

```
$str = '{ "name" : " Test Subject" }';
$obj = json_decode($str);
$obj->name = trim($obj->name);

$str = json_encode($obj);  // back to JSON string
var_dump($str);
```

The output:

```
string(23) "{"name":"Test Subject"}"
```

Comment: Looks like Great Minds Think Alike

Comment: @emilkitua, you're welcome